# Will changing the value of $drupal_hash_salt in settings.php file break site

Tags: security, users, configuration

I was looking through a list of steps to take when there is a risk that your site has been hacked.  It recommends changing the value of `$drupal_hash_salt` in settings.php.

According to the inline comments in settings.php:

> Salt for one-time login links and cancel links, form tokens, etc.
>
> This variable will be set to a random value by the installer. All one-time
>   login links will be invalidated if the value is changed. Note that if your
>   site is deployed on a cluster of web servers, you must ensure that this
>   variable has the same value on each server. If this variable is empty, a hash
>   of the serialized database credentials will be used as a fallback salt.

Can I simply replace the existing value with random string?  I am worried that changing this string may adversely effect some other aspect of site functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disruption should be minimal -- the salt value was designed to be changeable. As it says, it will invalidate one-time login links when the salt is changed. But if you suspect that you've been hacked, this is precisely what you want to happen.

Comment: So if I change it then any one-time login links previous to the change will be invalid.  However, any one-time login link generated after changing $drupal_hash_salt should work as per normal.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.